# Required meta-tags unreadable on hover

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design, design

the required meta tags (bug, discussion, ...) are unreadable on hover:

[image]

Link to page is https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/tags

**My system**: Windows, Firefox 58.0.2

Comment: reproduced on chrome (latest)

Comment: One of the designers has been notified about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks for reporting this bug. Fix is already waiting in repo and should be up on site in couple hours.

Comment: I will accept this in the moment I can see the results of the bug fix

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed now.